# Convert a string which contains a time value back to epoc in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

I have a json which has a value

```
"created": "2013-08-15T12:04:04Z"
```

i am parsing that value to a string in my code and want to convert this back to epoc time.

i can get to epoc like this but it not giving me an accurate value

```
timestamp = '2013-08-15T12:24:04Z'

t = Time.new(timestamp).to_f

puts t
```

i also tried `DateTime.parse` but not getting the correct value of the seconds and hours.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'time'
timestamp = '2013-08-15T12:24:04Z'
time = Time.parse(timestamp)
```

Comment: @SurajitRoy if it is working for your then could you accept the answer ?